# In VS2008, where is the configuration stores?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

not the project configuration, but the VS2008 general config one including Tools|Options|VC Directories...

is this an XML file anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

In VS08 check:

Tools > Options > Environment > Import and Export Settings.

Answer (score 1):

It is physically stored in the registry, spread out across the keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

The .vssettings file you get out of Tools + Import/Export + Export is an XML file.